# Convert sql to criteria builder statement

Tags: hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

I have a jsonb column, what I want to achieve to convert this SQL statement, noting that properties column is a jsonb column

```
select * from users where properties->>'actor' ilike '%tom%';
```

I managed to do this exact statement but with equal not like

```
    Predicate p = criteriaBuilder.equal(criteriaBuilder.function("jsonb_extract_path_text",
    String.class, pathVar,
    criteriaBuilder.literal("actor")), "Tom cruze" );
```

Any idea how to create this but for like

Not I tried this one but not working

```
Predicate p = criteriaBuilder.like(criteriaBuilder.function("jsonb_extract_path_text",
                                String.class, criteriaBuilder.lower((Expression<String>) pathVar),
criteriaBuilder.literal("actor")), String.valueOf("%tom%")).toLowerCase() );
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer, we need to wrap the expression with lower function and also the searched value with lower function

```
Expression<String> exp = criteriaBuilder.function("jsonb_extract_path_text", String.class, pathVar,
                                criteriaBuilder.literal("actor"));
Predicate p = criteriaBuilder.like(criteriaBuilder.lower(exp), "<%search_value%>".toLowerCase()  );
```